# How do I use single quotes inside single quotes php?

Tags: php, html, single-quotes

Can anyone explain how to make this code work?

```
echo '<li class="list-clients__item">
      <img src="<?php get_field('brand_logo'); ?>" height="75" width="168" alt="'.$category->cat_name.'"> 
      <span class="helper"></span> 
      </li>';
```

Comment: Mmm, you got to tell some more details what's not working, and what error messages its throwing, if any.. to make it easy to understand/answer

Comment: You can't nest `<?php…` code section in a string/echo statement anyway.

Comment: Dont use `<?php` when in PHP. Concatenate.

Comment: PD of [Can you put PHP inside PHP with echo?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15228026)

Answer (score 1):

You have nested php tags inside a php function call.

```
<?php get_field('brand_logo'); ?>
```

This is to execute php within dynamic html (e.g .phtml).

Stay with dynamic html

```
<li class="list-clients__item"> 
  <img src="<?php echo get_field('brand_logo'); ?>" height="75" width="168" alt="<?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>">
  <span class="helper"></span> 
</li>
```

or remove the nesting php tags

```
echo '<li class=\"list-clients__item\"> 
        <img src=\"' . get_field('brand_logo') . '\" height=\"75\" width=\"168\" alt=\"' . $category->cat_name . '\"> 
        <span class=\"helper\"></span> 
      </li>';
```

Comment: Guessing `get_field` will not do an echo, so inside your dynamic html version it should either include `echo` or rewrite to a short echo `<?=get_field('brand_logo')?>`.(there is also some missing attribute escaping worth mentioning)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
echo '<li class="list-clients__item"> <img src="'. get_field('brand_logo', 'category_' . $category->cat_ID) .'" height="75" width="168" alt="'.$category->cat_name.'"> <span class="helper"></span> </li>';
```

Comment: It gives me src unknown

Comment: Same  src unknown

Comment: Do you want to get category item's **brand_logo** ? If it is not category I advice you read this https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, remove the php tag.

Also to excape the quotes you use the \ (escape character).

ex. `echo 'tom\'s rest'`

```
echo '<li class="list-clients__item">
      <img src="'.get_field('brand_logo') .'" height="75" width="168" alt="'.$category->cat_name.'"> 
      <span class="helper"></span> 
      </li>';
```

Comment: It gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined function field()

Comment: is field a function or an array ?

Comment: @Vidal `field` is not a function, the function is called `get_field`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to embed a bunch of variables and functions into a longish string (of HTML), I find using the following format easier to read:

```
$brand_logo = get_field('brand_logo');
echo <<<EOF
<li class="list-clients__item">
    <img src="{$brand_logo}" height="75" width="168" alt="{$category->cat_name}">
    <span class="helper"></span>
</li>
EOF;
```

It's called the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) format.

Comment: Can't call functions(`get_field`) inside the string. Also worth noting that some editors prefer you to change EOF to HTML for correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: @René good spot, I'm used to class methods, and they _do_ work. Fixed it now. I'm not sure about all editors, but PhpStorm handles heredoc quite well.

Comment: It gives me src unknown

Comment: @Remon, that probably means brand_logo is either not defined at all or you're returning a wrong data type. It seems you've not given enough of your project in your post to create a clear answer.

Comment: @René i created a new field in categories section with the name brand_logo using custom field plugin and i need to show this category logo in homepage  this is my case so how can u help me to show this custom field?